# git pull in shared project folder

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions

On one of my Linux boxes I have a project folder where many developers do git operations - mainly `git pull`. The problem I'm having is that for some reason git creates new directories with wrong group permissions rwxrw-r--

I already set `sharedRepository = group` in `.git/config` and each user has umask set to `umask u=rw,g=rw,o=r`

What else should I do to fix this.

Again the problem is when a developer issues `git pull` the new directories are created with wrong permissions.

Comment: Do you mean the working copy is shared between developers?

Comment: Yes it's a www test server. Developer logs in via ssh and in project directory issues `git pull`